# Get current index in array_walk function

Tags: php, array-walk

```
$A = ["0" => "a", "1" => "b", "2" => "c"];
$B = ["0" => "aa", "1" => "bb", "2" => "cc"]
array_walk($A,function($item) use($B){
     $temp[] = $item;
     $temp[] = $B[?];
});
```

how to fill the ? above?   how to get the current index in array_walk?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? Please show your desired output.

Comment: @ObjectManipulator $temp=["0"=>["a","aa"],"1"=>["b","bb"],"2"=>["c","cc"]]

Comment: @PaulCrovella sorry i dont understand...make no sense to me,more exactly?

Comment: @PaulCrovella thanks a lot ,I understand after tried,hhh,so stupid question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly something like that would work

```
$A = ["0" => "a", "1" => "b", "2" => "c"];
$B = ["0" => "aa", "1" => "bb", "2" => "cc"]
array_walk($A,function($item, $key) use($B){
     $temp[] = $item;
     $temp[] = $B[$key];
});
```